# Magento 2 Add column in customer grid with name approve_account

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-attribute, customer-grid

I want to add a column in the customer grid with the name **`approve_account`**, it is not displaying in the gird. when I change the name (**`approve_account`**) to different names like **`approve_accounts`** it displays in heading with no column data. But I already created a customer attribute with name **`approve_account`** so I to add this in the customer grid.
My **`customer_listing.xml`** file

```
<columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
<column name="approve_account">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
             <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
             <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
             <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
             <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Approved</item>
             <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">51</item>
             <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
             <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
             <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>

            </item>
        </argument>
</column>
```

Note : Its worked in local server. Issue in production (Both having same code)

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the code of how did you create the customer attribute **approve_account** and which type of attribute it is.

If you want to display your attribute with values in the **Customer Grid** then you will have to set below given attribute option as **Yes (1)**

```
is_used_in_grid => 1
```

If it is set to **1 (Yes)** then only, you can display the attribute column in the **Customer Grid** with values.

Comment: already assign is_used_in_grid=>1 and etc/indexer.xml also, still not displaying in customer grid.

Comment: Is it 'Yes/No' attribute OR Dropdown?